# JQuery text search: can't get the right tag/element to search table text

Tags: jquery, search, html-table

I am using HTML to read an XML file and build a table.  I'm using code I found on a w3schools.com tutorial, and that part works fine.

I am trying to get a search function to find (and if possible highlight) text within the table.  I found JQuery code at https://www.thriveuk.com/quick-tips-how-to-search-on-a-page-for-text-and-highlight-it/ which works great on his page and does exactly what I'd like to see.  He mentioned the code could easily be modified to search the whole page, but I can't figure it out.  I have contacted the developer, but he hasn't answered.

I really only need to search text within the table.  I'm sure the search fail is in the syntax referencing the search area, and may be connected with how the table builds up in code.  If anyone can show me what I'm doing wrong in referencing the table as the search area, I'd appreciate it.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Style the input */
.on-page-search {
width: 65%;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 26px;
color: #787d85;
background-color: #fcfcfc;
border: 1px solid #e0e1e1;
padding: 5px 15px;
}

/* Style the list */
.demo-links {
border-bottom: none;
padding: 5px 5px;
line-height: 36px;
}

/* Style the results */
.results {
background: #de1919;
color: white;
}
.results:hover {
background: #333;
color: white;
}

</style>

<!--  https://www.thriveuk.com/quick-tips-how-to-search-on-a-page-for-text-and-highlight-it/ -->

<body>

<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>Enter text to search this page.</p>
<p></p>

<input class="on-page-search"></input>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".on-page-search").on("keyup", function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        $(".results").removeClass("results");

        //I'm pretty sure the problem is here:
        $("table td").each(function(){

            if (v != "" && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(v,'gi')) != -1) {
                $(this).addClass("results");
            }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>

<p>Click on a name to display information.</p>
<p id='showCD'></p>
<div id="data">
<table id="demo"></table>
</div>

<script>
var x,xmlhttp,xmlDoc
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Incidents.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INC");
table="<tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Type</th></tr>";
for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr onclick='displayCD(" + i + ")'><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("LNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("FNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("TYPE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><tr>";
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

function displayCD(i) {
  document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML =
  "Last: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("LNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>First: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("FNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Date: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Offense: " + 
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("TYPE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have tried different terms in "$("table td").each(function(){".  I have tried the table id name; creating a separate div for the table and referencing that; I found a way to reference all the rows in a table; and various terms to reference the content and body of the doc. The solution feels *right there* and probably obvious to others.

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work!  I discovered the developer's tools in Edge and the bumbled through the console.  First error was no reference to jQuery, so I added that.  Then I had some tags in the wrong place.  Finally, I ran over the elements and realized I needed to search each  - I also didn't realize at first that this was an iterative search, looping through each element.  It's finished, and the table row with the input text will highlight.  (Now I just need to find a way to clear the highlight!)

The adjusted page is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<style>
table,th,td {
  border : 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}
th,td {
  padding: 5px;
}

/* Style the input */
.on-page-search {
width: 65%;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 26px;
color: #787d85;
background-color: #fcfcfc;
border: 1px solid #e0e1e1;
padding: 5px 15px;
}

/* Style the list */
.demo-links {
border-bottom: none;
padding: 5px 5px;
line-height: 36px;
}

/* Style the results */
.results {
background: #de1919;
color: white;
}
.results:hover {
background: #333;
color: white;
}

</style>

</head>

<!--  https://www.thriveuk.com/quick-tips-how-to-search-on-a-page-for-text-and-highlight-it/ -->

<body>

<p></p>
<p></p>
<p>Enter text to search this page.</p>
<p></p>

<input class="on-page-search"></input>
<p></p>
<p></p>

<script type='text/javascript'>
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(".on-page-search").on("keyup", function () {
        var v = $(this).val();
        $(".results").removeClass("results");
        $("tr").each(function(){
            if (v != "" && $(this).text().search(new RegExp(v,'gi')) != -1) {
                $(this).addClass("results");
            }
        });
    });
}); 
</script>

<p>Click on a name to display information.</p>
<p id='showCD'></p>
<div id="data">
<table id="demo">

<script>
var x,xmlhttp,xmlDoc
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "Incidents.xml", false);
xmlhttp.send();
xmlDoc = xmlhttp.responseXML; 
x = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("INC");
table="<tr><th>Last Name</th><th>First Name</th><th>Date</th><th>Type</th></tr>";
for (i = 0; i <x.length; i++) { 
    table += "<tr onclick='displayCD(" + i + ")'><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("LNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("FNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><td>";
    table += x[i].getElementsByTagName("TYPE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    table += "</td><tr>";
  }
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = table;

function displayCD(i) {
  document.getElementById("showCD").innerHTML =
  "Last: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("LNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>First: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("FNAME")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Date: " +
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("DATE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue +
  "<br>Offense: " + 
  x[i].getElementsByTagName("TYPE")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
}
</script>

</table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```